# how to make audios copy right like gaana app

Tags: android

I have been developing an app which contains audios and now I want users to download those audio and can play only through my app. By doing this we can restrict user from copying audios from one device to another because of security concerns. I have searched a lot but only found DRM(Digiatal Right management) is used to restrict the user. As per early study Digital rights management (DRM) is a systematic approach to copyright protection for digital media.

But I am not able to find any real practical example of DRM nor there is any kind of documentation. I would really appreciate if somebody tell me how to start with such technologies.